# qemu on linux specifying boot order

Tags: linux, boot, virtualization

I am attempting to define multiple drives for my virtual machine.

I am attempting to get things working with one drive and advance from there...

I have success getting qemu to launch using this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -m 4G \
   -boot d \
   -enable-kvm \
   -smp 2 \
   -net nic -net user \
   -hda ${HOME}/vm/disk.img \
   -cdrom ${HOME}/downloads/iso/os.iso
```

however, as I said I am planning on adding more drives to my virtual machine to test some things...

I have tried this command but the VM throws: Could not read from CDROM (code 0003) and fails to boot

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -m 4G \
   -boot d \
   -enable-kvm \
   -smp 2 \
   -net nic -net user \
   -drive file=${HOME}/vm/disk.img,index=0,media=disk \
   -drive file=${HOME}/downloads/iso/os.iso,index=1,media=cdrom
```

If i leave off the -boot d and the .iso -drive the machine will boot into disk.img...

Any Ideas what is going on here? or how to fix my second command so I can boot from cdrom and use the -drive tag?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone sees this on on search, I got it to work using this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \ 
   -m 4G \
   -boot d \
   -enable-kvm \                                                              
   -smp 2 \                                                                   
   -net nic -net user \                                                       
   -drive file=${HOME}/vm/arch/disk0.img,index=0,media=disk \                 
   -drive file=${HOME}/vm/arch/disk1.img,index=1,media=disk \                 
   -drive file=${HOME}/downloads/iso/os.iso,index=2,media=cdrom,readonly
```